# Need VBA to grab value from cell instead of text within VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need this VBA to instead of just putting the value "X" in cells to grab the text from a cell within the work book. The cell is B4 within the Sheet "Order Entry". Thanks.

```
Sub Check()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Sheets("Customer List").Range("D2:D100")
    dat = rng.Value
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
            rng(i, -2).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Confused as to how this is off topic

Comment: Try: `rng(i, -2) = Sheets("Order Entry").Range("B4").Value`

Comment: I didn't follow. Can you illustrate what you want to achieve? Just using simple data that is, before and after.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Check()
Dim dat As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set rng = Sheets("Customer List").Range("D2:D100")
dat = rng.Value
For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
    If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
        rng(i, -2).Value = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Order Entry").Range("B4").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```